# Can i use multiple conditions inside where clause in this query?

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

```
$sql="SELECT user_id, user_fname, user_lname, telephone, primary_email, dept_name, created_date, st_name, emp_level_name
            FROM ".$prefix."users_info, 
            ".$prefix."support_departments,
            /".$prefix."user_status,
            ".$prefix."company_user_levels
            WHERE ".$prefix."users_info.dept_id=".$prefix."support_departments.dept_id,
            ".$prefix."users_info.user_st=".$prefix."user_status.user_st,
            ".$prefix."users_info.user_level=".$prefix."company_user_levels.emp_level_id
            ORDER BY ".$sort_para." ";
            $employee_info = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
```

Comment: Please for the love of sanity use Prepared Statements, PDO or MySQLi

Comment: If you use AND and OR with them, rather than just separating them with commas. e.g. `WHERE (X=1 AND Y=2) OR Z=3` - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the WHERE statement, replace the comas by " AND ":

```
$sql = "SELECT user_id, user_fname, user_lname, telephone, primary_email, dept_name, created_date, st_name, emp_level_name
FROM ${prefix}users_info, ${prefix}support_departments, ${prefix}user_status, ${prefix}company_user_levels
WHERE ${prefix}users_info.dept_id=${prefix}support_departments.dept_id AND ${prefix}users_info.user_st=${prefix}user_status.user_st AND ${prefix}users_info.user_level=${prefix}company_user_levels.emp_level_id
ORDER BY ".$sort_para;
$employee_info = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with putting "AND" or "OR" clauses between conditions instead of comma?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use join for getting data from multiple tables,

```
FROM ".$prefix."users_info ui    
join  ".$prefix."user_status su on su.FOREIGNKEY = ui.PRIMARY
```

Also in where condition you need to use AND or OR conditions in between each condition

```
WHERE ".$prefix."users_info.dept_id=".$prefix."support_departments.dept_id AND 
        ".$prefix."users_info.user_st=".$prefix."user_status.user_st
```